# Having problems with net::ssh::multi can't require it! Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, net-ssh

So I've tried to install net::ssh::multi on mac using gems:

```
gems install net-ssh-multi
```

The installation went fine, however when I type:

```
require 'net/ssh/multi'
```

it says load error.
I have no idea whats wrong with what I'm doing!

Comment: More information would be useful! Probably just a problem with rubygems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh/multi'
```

...should take care of you.